# Python slicing and splitting data from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def read_slice():

    openfile=open('slicefile1.txt','r')
    #savetofile=open('slicefile2.txt','w')


    lines = openfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line.slice(',')[16].split('\t')
        print(line)
```

The file that I want to read and parse ( is that the correct word?) is in the format

```
['05,21,34,37,38,01,06', '09,16,26,36,39,02,06', '03,10,18,31,37,02,04'].
```

I want to return ( actually write to another file) in the format

```
05,21,34,37,38 tab 01,06
09,16,26,36,39 tab 02,06
```

I am obviously stupid because I still cannot handle lists and strings. The function gives an error method slice not available of string. Please help if you would

Comment: Whoops! There should be a new line between tab 01,06 and 09,... etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicing in python strings refers to using the [`[start:stop:step]` notation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings). In your case, you can simply use:

```
'\t'.join((line[:14], line[15:]))
```

to split the line and rejoin it with a tab:

```
>>> line = '05,21,34,37,38,01,06'
>>> line[:14]
'05,21,34,37,38'
>>> line[15:]
'01,06'
>>> '\t'.join((line[:14], line[15:]))
'05,21,34,37,38\t01,06'
```

Comment: Is it worth mentioning ``"\t".join((line[:-6:], line[-5::]))`` ? in that this is more about the last bit of the line and yours is about the beginning of the line. In that yours will work now matter how many digits follow and this will work no matter how many precede the last pair. It's a subtle point and very much depends on why the OP needs to split the list by ``\t``.

Comment: @sotapme: Perhaps; the OP doesn't specify *how* fixed the format is.

Comment: Tank you. Works perfectly. Reason for this format is that I am too stupid using slice and split to be able to parse without this format. I really need to do a tutorial to explore this properly and get the logic into my frustratingly thick skull

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more complicated that Martijn's answer, but perhaps more flexible if changes to formatting or delimiters etc... occur:

```
import csv

with open('yourfile') as fin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    csvout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csvin:
        csvout.writerow( [','.join(row[:5], ','.join(row[5:])] )
```

Comment: A side note: For Python 3, the `open` for csv file must have slightly different arguments.